# How to correctly set a colorbar for an external graphic?

Tags: pgfplots, external-files

I created a pdf file from a Matlab imagesc plot. I have remove the colorbar and axis and now I want to have this image in my tex document. I manged to get the axes almost as I want them, but the colorbar won't work. There is no error, but also no colorbar. What am I missing?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis on top,title=Test,colormap/jet]
 \addplot graphics[xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=1,zmin=0,zmax=.5]
   {image.pdf};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You forgot to supply `colorbar`, i.e. `\begin{axis}[colorbar, axis on...`

Comment: Well, I just realized that I have a nice colorbar, but the labels are wrong. I gave the zmin and zmax because I thought this would make it right, but apparently it doesn't... My image is a Matlab imagesc plot, so I have x and y, but the color indicates height. How do I change labels on a colorbar?

Comment: You could try `\addplot[point meta min=0, point meta max=0.5] graphics[xmin=0,...`